# Inter component communication in polymer 2

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

i have two custom components named `form-data1` and `form-data2` and placed these two components in another component. I want to pass filled data from `form-data1` to `form-data2`

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong to understand. This is the most easy approach in Polymer.

> form-data.html

```
<form-data1 data-one="{{dataOne}}"></form-data1>
<form-data2 data-one="{{dataOne}}"></form-data2>
```

dataOne may contain an onject which you filled a form in form-data1.html or form-data2.html and same property will be at both component. 
(Don't forget to declare dataOne property in form-data1 or/and form-data2  something lile in form-data1:

```
  class FormData1 extends Polymer.Element { 
        static get is() { return 'forn-data1'; }
        static get properties() { return {   
        dataOne:{
            type: Object,
            notify:true
        }
        }}
```

Or please specify more detail for your own needs.